# Can I make the same preamble appear for every document?

Tags: preamble

I have a lot of commands and packages in my preamble so right now I just have to copy and paste the entire preamble every time I am making a new document. Is there any way to make the same preamble appear in every new document without doing this?

Comment: You could write a package and put it in your user's texmf. Then you would only have to load one package in your preamble (yours).

Comment: @Skillmon how do you write a package?

Comment: Or you could just use \input{preamble} for some preamble.tex.  Adding a sty file is not automatic with MikTeX.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the comment *How do you write a package?* here is a very simple package called `pack`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pack}[2018/09/06]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% your preamble code here, and that's it
```

This is all treated in much more detail in **A.4 Package and class file structure** in Mittelbach and Goossens' *The LaTeX Companion (2nd edition)*. Maybe of particular interest it deals with `options` and how to call for a package within your package (by `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`). You could, of course, look at the source of any packages on your system to see how they are structured.

Comment: You should perhaps mention, that one generally uses `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` to load packages inside of a package by convention.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you use a document class already. So what you could do is create your own document class by adapting the one you are using. Say you are using the article class. Say also that you want to write a new paper called Paper1

Steps:

1. Open your LaTEx editor and create a new file.
2. Write the following at the start (where in my example the word ‘myclass’ refers to the name of the new document class you are creating. You can use another name if you want):

   \ProvidesClass{myclass}
   \LoadClassWithOptions{article}
3. Copy all your usual preamble options and commands.

Basically, the command \Load...will load all the options and commands of the class article. Your own stuff will override that, as well as add your own style, etc.

4. Save this file as a class file (.cls), to the same folder in which you will save Paper1. Use the same filename as class name!
5. Create a new file. At the top, write:
   \documentclass{myclass}

You are ready to begin writing your paper, in the normal way. It should look something like this:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Bits of text.   

\end{document}
```